# Pandas - Create a column increment based on another column for groups based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

Based on a dataset with customer_id and customer_type, I want to create another column named order_number which finds out how many times that customer has returned. If, for that customer_id, there is a First-time, set that to 1 and increment for the subsequent orders. If there isn't a First-time within the dataset for that customer, set to None.

| order_time | customer_id | customer_type | order_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 1 | First-time | 1 |
| x2 | 1 | Returning | 2 |
| x3 | 1 | Returning | 3 |
| x4 | 1 | Returning | 4 |
| x5 | 2 | Returning | NaN |
| x6 | 2 | Returning | NaN |
| x7 | 3 | First-time | 1 |
| x8 | 3 | Returning | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["order_number"] = df.groupby("customer_id")["customer_type"].transform(
    lambda x: x.eq("First-time").replace(False, np.nan).ffill().cumsum()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  order_time  customer_id customer_type  order_number
0         x1            1    First-time           1.0
1         x2            1     Returning           2.0
2         x3            1     Returning           3.0
3         x4            1     Returning           4.0
4         x5            2     Returning           NaN
5         x6            2     Returning           NaN
6         x7            3    First-time           1.0
7         x8            3     Returning           2.0
```